# How to check a variable of main thread within a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that is running:

```
public boolean shouldStopThread = false;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {

                   if(!shouldStopThread )
                     {
                      // Do my stop here
                     }
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }).start();
```

The problem is when I change the boolean from `false` to `true` the change isn't detected within the thread.

How do I get the boolean within the thread to detect the change?

Comment: when you are starting this thread, after changing ?

Comment: Can you post the whole code to test ? With the two threads. There might be an error/a misconception in your test case.

Answer (score 2):

Since your boolean is *not* [`volatile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), it is not guaranteed to change immediately in all threads.

If you declare it to be `volatile`, it is guaranteed that every time the value is changed, it will be seen across all threads.

Comment: They could also use an `AtomicBoolean`

Comment: @JeremyGrand Correct, here's the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

Comment: @MarounMaroun i set it to volatile and the thread didnt detect the change

Comment: @nicko_yuan How do you know it didn't "detect"? Did you change the `if` to `while`?

Comment: @nicko_yuan Do you know how references work in java ? Simply reaffecting a `boolean` (primitive) might not do what you think it does. Your `Thread` encapsulated the actual value (`false`) rather than the reference to `shouldStopThread `. That's why it might be better to use the `AtomicBoolean`

Answer (score 2):

you could use [AtomicBoolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). It is *like* a `boolean` but its value gets updated atomically

Answer (score 0):

Your thread just check if condition and stop it's execution. You should wait or use infinite cycle in your code to check condition:

```
while(!shouldStopThread )
{
   // Do my stop here
}
```

or

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
if (!shouldStopThread )
{
   // Do my stop here
}
```

In second case you have only 1 second to set `shouldStopThread` to `true` value.

And `shouldStopThread` should be `volatile`.